Extract the Time stamp from a version 1 GUID using c#
I need to examine a large file containing thousands of elements each identified by a GUID to get the date and time the element was created. I found a web site https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen?typeReq=-1 which when given one of the GUID's I need to parse came back with the correct value and identifies it as a version 1 GUID, but I need to do this for hundreds of GUID's so the on-line approach is impractical.
My current code looks like
        public DateTime ExtractTimestampFromUUID(string uuid)
        {
            // split the UUID into its components
            var parts = uuid.Split('-');

            var xx = parts[0] + parts[1];

            // the second part of the UUID contains the high bits of the timestamp (48 bits in total)
            var highBitsHex = parts[0] + parts[1].Substring(0, 4);

            // convert the high bits from hex to decimal
            var timestampInMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt64(highBitsHex, 16);

            // convert the timestamp to a DateTime object
            var date = new DateTime(timestampInMilliseconds);

            return date;
        }

but this creates a value which is too high for the DateConvert routine.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Quote: the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight 15 October 1582.  Not milliseconds.

Thanks Mark - I had to make a minor change as it looks like the .Net tick counter is different to Python. My code looks like:
        public DateTime ExtractTime(string GUID)
        {
            var Parts = GUID.Split('-');           

            // 100-ns intervals since 10/15/1582 00:00:00.  60 bits.
            // Trim off 1st digit of parts[2] as it is the UUID version.
            //           12 bits    +  16 bits + 32 bits
            var HexTime = Parts[2].Substring(1) + Parts[1] + Parts[0];
            var Time = Convert.ToInt64(HexTime, 16);

            var Epoch = new DateTime(1582, 10, 15);
            var Diff = TimeSpan.FromTicks(Time);
            
            return Epoch.Add(Diff);
        }


The math is wrong.  My C# is rusty and don't have a C# compiler handy to verify so here's working code in Python to use as pseudocode:
import datetime as dt

s = 'A5257A55-0DE3-11ED-A2E5-005056A3A023'

parts = s.split('-')

# 100-ns intervals since 10/15/1582 00:00:00.  60 bits.
# Trim off 1st digit of parts[2] as it is the UUID version.
#           12 bits    +  16 bits + 32 bits
hextime = parts[2][1:] + parts[1] + parts[0]
time = int(hextime, 16)

epoch = dt.datetime(1582, 10, 15)
diff = dt.timedelta(microseconds=time / 10)
print(epoch + diff)

Output:
2022-07-27 19:38:09.778748

